# Google Apps Script: Sheets: Append data from an input range in Sheet1 to a dataset in Sheet2

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create an input field in a google spreadsheet to enable simple data collection, but I'm having some trouble with a for loop. I'm a JS novice, and this is the first time I've attempted to use Google Apps Script.

App logic:
- data entered into a input field ("Sheet1!F13:F36")
- button with script assigned is clicked
- data is loaded from the input field and appended to a dataset in Sheet2

Please see my code below:

```js
function appendToDB() {
  
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var dashboard = ss.getSheetByName("Dashboard");
 var inputRange = dashboard.getRange("F13:F36");
 var db =  ss.getSheetByName("Database");
 var storeName = dashboard.getRange("C7").getValue();
 var category = dashboard.getRange("C9").getValue();  
  
  for(var i=0; i<inputRange.length; i++){
   
   var currentCellValue = inputRange[i].getValue();
   
   db.appendRow([storeName,category,currentCellValue]);
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following [`dashboard.getRange("F13:F36")`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(String)) function returns a range class not an array. Hence when you do try to get a length like so `inputRange.length` you get a return of undefined and loop is never run.

You can get the values of the cells by using [`getValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) and run through the array in loop and append the values to the db sheet like so

```
function appendToDB() {

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var dashboard = ss.getSheetByName("Dashboard");
 var inputRange = dashboard.getRange("F13:F36").getValues();  //returns a 2D array
 var db =  ss.getSheetByName("Database");
 var storeName = dashboard.getRange("C7").getValue();
 var category = dashboard.getRange("C9").getValue();  

  for(var i=0; i<inputRange.length; i++){

   var currentCellValue = inputRange[i][0];

   db.appendRow([storeName,category,currentCellValue]);
  }

}
```

Equivalently, you can use [`getNumRows()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnumrows) function of range class, to get the number of rows. Use that as a counter to loop through to get individual values of individual cell by [`getCell(row,column).getValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getcellrow-column)

Which would look like this:

```
function appendToDB() {

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var dashboard = ss.getSheetByName("Dashboard");
 var inputRange = dashboard.getRange("F13:F36");
 var db =  ss.getSheetByName("Database");
 var storeName = dashboard.getRange("C7").getValue();
 var category = dashboard.getRange("C9").getValue();  

  for(var i=1; i<=inputRange.getNumRows(); i++){

   var currentCellValue = inputRange.getCell(i,1).getValue();

   db.appendRow([storeName,category,currentCellValue]);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked. You saved me a sleepless night!